# Trying to insert belongsToMany relationships

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Trying to insert belongsToMany relationships:

```
$currentPerson->fbevents()->attach($currentEvent);
```

$currentPerson is:

```
{
    "name": "xxxx",
    "userId": "yyyyyyy",
    "pictureUrl": "zzzzz"
}
```

Shows that $currentPerson has no id, even though it's just been inserted into the database with `$currentPerson->save();`

So, I guess the question is how do I get the correct entry in the pivot table? The models are like this:

User.php:

```
public function fbevents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Fbevent', 'fbevent_user');
}
```

Fbevent.php:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'fbevent_user');
}
```

$currentPerson is of type User, and $currentEvent is of type Fbevent.

At the moment I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dmf`.`fbevent_user`, CONSTRAINT `fbevent_user_fbevent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`fbevent_id`) REFERENCES `fbevents` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `fbevent_user` () values ())
```

Migration schema:

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('userId');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('pictureUrl');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('fbevents', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('eventId');
    $table->string('pageId');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('description', 500);
    $table->datetime('start');
    $table->datetime('end');
    $table->string('picture');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

fbevent_user:

```
Schema::create('fbevent_user', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('fbevent_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('fbevent_id')->references('id')->on('fbevents')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: show tables schema and actual code where you create those entries.

Comment: I've added the schema - the code is really as I've put, just `$currentPerson->save();`, which correctly inputs the User and id, etc. and then `$currentPerson->fbevents()->attach($currentEvent);`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, and what's `$currentEvent`?

Comment: It would seem as though you need to call `$currentEvent->save()`.  After making sure the event and person are both saved, make sure both have id's `echo $currentEvent->id; echo $currentPerson->id;`.  Then you should be able to insert those into the pivot table using `$currentPerson->fbevents()->attach($currentEvent);`.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `attach()` by `save()`

```
$currentPerson->save();
$currentPerson->fbevents()->save($currentEvent);
```